# Issue with cursor position in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, signalr

I am using tinyMCE as a plugin in my ASP.NET MVC4 web application. I am also using SignalR to establish an open connection between the server and the clients. What I am trying to do is a real-time editor similar to Google Docs.

Until now I managed to find a way to write in an editor in one browser and have it displayed in another open document in another browser. I previously had a problem with the cursor position since when I was using the setContent() method in tinyMCE, the cursor was being put to the front and therefore the output was reversed.

This was solved by these two statements:

```
ed.selection.select(ed.getBody(), true); 
ed.selection.collapse(false);
```

However now the problem I have is that with Chrome the output is as I wish for it to be i.e. writing with the cursor at the back however when I write from a Firefox browser, the space button is ignored, when I press space, the cursor goes back.

Is there a particular reason why this happened? Also, there seems to be a speed issue with the connection i.e when I type fast the latest content (1 or 2 letters) are not submitted.

This is all the code I have regarding this problem:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "- Editor";
    ViewBag.ContentStyle = "/Content/CSS/editor.css";
}

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/tinyMCE/tiny_mce.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/EditorHandler.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advanced",
            plugins: "emotions,spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview",

            // Theme options - button# indicated the row# only
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,code,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "insertdate,inserttime,|,spellchecker,advhr,,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing: false,

            setup: function (ed) {
                ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {
                    var chat = $.connection.editorHub;

                    chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(message);
                        ed.selection.select(ed.getBody(), true); 
                        ed.selection.collapse(false);
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();
                    };

                    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                        var text = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
                        chat.server.send(text);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
        <textarea id="editor" name="content" cols="100" rows="30"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might want to check out the possibility to get a tinymce bookmark.
There are html bookmarks which are implemented using hidden spans with a certain class.
And there are non-html bookmarks - i would use those.

```
// gets you a non-html bookmark which you can transfer to another server if need be
var bookmark = editor.selection.getBookmark(2, true);
editor.setContent(content);
editor.selection.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
```

Comment: tried to use this just now.. still with the same problem of spacing in firefox! thanks for your answer :)